# How to fix data type size?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a doubt on my table data sizes.
how to fix data type and its size exactly.
Please help me here.

```
mysql> show create table AssignmentPolicy\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: AssignmentPolicy
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `AssignmentPolicy` (
  `AssignmentPolicyID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AssignmentPolicyGroupID` smallint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `AssignmentPolicyName` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `AssignmentPolicyTitle` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `AssignmentPolicyDescription` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `Order` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Editable` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `DefaultValue` tinyint(1) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Dependency` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AssignmentPolicyID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


Tables:

mysql> show create table Item\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: Item
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `Item` (
  `Item_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Reviewer_User_ID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Author_User_ID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status_Code` enum('live','in_progress','needs_revision','ready_for_review','ready_for_final_review','hidden','deprecated') DEFAULT 'in_progress',
  `Topic_ID` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Cognitive_Type` enum('conceptual','quantitative','vocabulary') DEFAULT NULL,
  `Difficulty` enum('easy','medium','hard') DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` mediumtext,
  `bookQNum` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Is_EOC` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Propagate_Algos` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Regenerate_Algos` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Visibility` enum('private','system') DEFAULT 'system',
  `Source_Taxonomy` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date_Created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ItemCopied_ID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `TemplateCopied_ID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ibis_compatible` enum('false','true') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'true',
  `sequoia_compatible` enum('false','true') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'false',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Item_ID`),
  KEY `Topic_ID` (`Topic_ID`),
  KEY `Status_Code` (`Status_Code`),
  KEY `Author_User_ID` (`Author_User_ID`),
  KEY `Reviewer_User_ID` (`Reviewer_User_ID`),
  KEY `ItemCopied_ID` (`ItemCopied_ID`),
  KEY `TemplateCopied_ID` (`TemplateCopied_ID`),
  KEY `Item2Taxonomy` (`Source_Taxonomy`),
  CONSTRAINT `Item2Author_User_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`Author_User_ID`) REFERENCES `User` (`userID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `Item2content__taxonomy` FOREIGN KEY (`Source_Taxonomy`) REFERENCES `content`.`taxonomy` (`Key`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `Item2content__topic` FOREIGN KEY (`Topic_ID`) REFERENCES `content`.`topic` (`Key`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `Item2Item_Copied` FOREIGN KEY (`ItemCopied_ID`) REFERENCES `Item` (`Item_ID`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `Item2Template_Copied` FOREIGN KEY (`TemplateCopied_ID`) REFERENCES `Item` (`Item_ID`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41885 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What's the problem? What's your question? *What have you tried?*

Comment: i  want modify my data types and its size for good performance.

Comment: That didn't answer any of my questions. StackExchange has strict guidelines on question quality, so your question will likely be closed. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numeric types such as int don't have dynamic size. If you set int(11) you set the padding level, not the "integer size" which is... you know... integer-sized after all. So on the first go I'd remove all int/tinyint/etc "(xx)" values if weren't intentional to set padding. If you want to change columns in a table you have to use ALTER TABLE, there are some fine examples here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table-examples.html